# Line break other than \n in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, line-breaks

The following b variable seems to have a last character corresponding to a line break but it is not the classical '\n' character. This is very embarrassing for print using this variable:

```
K>> b

b =

toto_titi


K>> fprintf('This strange variable (%s) is very strange !!!\n', b);
This strange variable (toto_titi
) is very strange !!!
```

Indeed, the needed print would be:

```
This strange variable (toto_titi) is very strange !!!
```

Below, few observed facts with this variable:

```
K>> class(b)

ans =

char

K>> [b 'end']

ans =

toto_titi
end

K>> b(end)

ans =




K>> regexp(b,'_', 'split')

ans = 

    'toto'    'titi…'
```

I confess that I do not exactely understand for the three dots in 'titi…' but I suppose that here is a part of the explanation !!!

A quick and dirty method will be to remove the last invisible character that cause the line break but if in other application the last caharacter in the b variable is a "real" character we will lost this last character (ex. toto_tit in place of  toto_titi).

A MATLAB equivalent of the python strip() exist ?

What is this invisible character in the b variable ?

**EDIT 1:**
A good idea, from rahnema1, is to determine what is the ASCII code for this invisible character:

```
K>> double(b)

ans =

   116   111   116   111    95   116   105   116   105    13

K>> for i = 1 : 60
str = [num2str(i) ' ' char(i) '     '...
num2str(i+32) ' ' char(i+32) '     '...
num2str(i+64) ' ' char(i+64)];
disp(str)
end
1      33 !     65 A
2      34 "     66 B
3      35 #     67 C
4      36 $     68 D
5      37 %     69 E
6      38 &     70 F
7      39 '     71 G
8     40 (     72 H
9        41 )     73 I
10 
     42 *     74 J
11      43 +     75 K
12      44 ,     76 L
13 
     45 -     77 M
14      46 .     78 N
15      47 /     79 O
16      48 0     80 P
17      49 1     81 Q
18      50 2     82 R
19      51 3     83 S
20      52 4     84 T
21      53 5     85 U
22      54 6     86 V
23      55 7     87 W
24      56 8     88 X
25      57 9     89 Y
26      58 :     90 Z
27      59 ;     91 [
28      60 <     92 \
29      61 =     93 ]
30      62 >     94 ^
31      63 ?     95 _
32       64 @     96 `
33 !     65 A     97 a
34 "     66 B     98 b
35 #     67 C     99 c
36 $     68 D     100 d
37 %     69 E     101 e
38 &     70 F     102 f
39 '     71 G     103 g
40 (     72 H     104 h
41 )     73 I     105 i
42 *     74 J     106 j
43 +     75 K     107 k
44 ,     76 L     108 l
45 -     77 M     109 m
46 .     78 N     110 n
47 /     79 O     111 o
48 0     80 P     112 p
49 1     81 Q     113 q
50 2     82 R     114 r
51 3     83 S     115 s
52 4     84 T     116 t
53 5     85 U     117 u
54 6     86 V     118 v
55 7     87 W     119 w
56 8     88 X     120 x
57 9     89 Y     121 y
58 :     90 Z     122 z
59 ;     91 [     123 {
60 <     92 \     124 |
```

**EDIT 2:**
Works around  the idea of rahnema1 and excaza:

. If we know the ASCII code (by using strrep):

```
K>> fprintf('This strange variable (%s) is very stange !!!\n', strrep(b,char(13),''));
This strange variable (toto_titi) is very stange !!!
```

. For remove leading and trailing whitespace (by using strtrim):

```
fprintf('This strange variable (%s) is very stange !!!\n', strtrim(b));
This strange variable (toto_titi) is very stange !!!
```

Comment: Try `K>> double(b)`

Comment: Oh this a very nice idea !!!!

Comment: Your idea is very good !!! So I know now that the ASCII code of the invisible character is the number 13 !!!! I edit my question with this capital information ! Thanks rahnema1.

Comment: [`strtrim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) will trim leading and trailing whitespace from strings.

Comment: 13 is equivalent to`'\r'`.

Comment: Thank you folks !!! all is clear now ...

Comment: The next time I will go to see the [ASCII table translation]  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ before to ask a silly question ;-)